Path-connectedness of union of line segments in $\mathbb R^2$ connecting $(0,1)$ to $(x,0)$ for $x\in [0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$
This is a past qualifying exam problem.

Let $X$ be the subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ obtained as the union of line segments connecting $(0,1)$ to $(x,0)$ for $x\in [0,1] \cap\mathbb Q$.


Is the space $X$ path connected?

I believe the answer is yes.
Reasoning: Let $x,y \in X$ be distinct points. If $x$ and $y$ lie on the same line segment, then there is an obvious path between them. Otherwise, if $x$ and $y$ lie on distinct line segments, let $p:[0,1]\to X$ be the path that travels from $x$ to $(0,1)$ along the unique line segment connecting them, then from $(0,1)$ to $y$ along the unique line segment connecting them.
I'm slightly confused about whether $p$ is continuous though. It seems like it should be, since its image "looks like" a subset of the graph of the real-valued function $x\mapsto |x|$, which is continuous everywhere. But maybe I'm missing something.
Is my reasoning correct? How to make the continuity of $p$ precise?

Concatenations of continuous functions are continuous.

@EricTowers Ah-hah! Concatenation. That's the word I should've thought of.

Union of path-connected sets with non-empty intersection is path-connected. Actually your set is a star domain.

@pyridoxal_trigeminus just look up what gluing lemma is.

Nice shortcut that I will keep in mind, thanks @Jakobian


Obviously the "linear path" $u : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2, u(t) = (1-t)\xi+ t\eta$, connecting two points $\xi,\eta \in \mathbb  R^2$ is continuous.
If the image of $u$ is contained in your $X$, then we can regard $u$ as a continuous map $u : [0,1]  \to X$ (because $X$ has the subspace topology ).

Given any two continuous paths $u, v : [0,1] \to Y$ (where $Y$ is any topological space) such that $u(1) = v(0)$, then the path
$$u * v : [0,1] \to Y, (u*v)(t) = \begin{cases} u(2t) & t \le 1/2 \\ v(2t-1) & t \ge 1/2 \end{cases}$$
is continuous.
To see this, observe that $u' : [0,1/2] \to Y, u'(t) = u(2t)$, and $v' : [1/2,1] \to Y, v'(t) = v(2t-1)$, are continuous and agree on $\{1/2\} = [0,1/2] \cap [1/2,1]$. Since $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$ are closed subsets of $[0,1]$, the map $u*v$ is continuous. This follows from the pasting lemma. Anyway, it should be clear that if $C \subset Y$ is closed, then $(u*v)^{-1}(C)  = (u')^{-1}(C) \cup (v')^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $[0,1]$.


From 1. and 2. you can easily conclude that $X$ is path connected.
